# Spring Security login on the basis of role selected by user from multiple roles assigned in db

Tags: spring, security

I have  a requirement in which I have to give feature so that for perticular user can select the roles from drop-down   . Roles will be in database.  And I have to map that role with the spring Security authentication.

Eg- If there is two roles Admin and User in database.  When Login I should be able to select user from drop-down and whole application should run on the basis of that role. If I select Admin then only admin should be mapped ,if I select User then user should be mapped.

Please help in that.

Thanks,

Comment: welcome. please read about how to ask a good question that is likely to get a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254991/spring-security-endpoint-protection-by-dynamic-roles/49258209#49258209